# Typeahead Bloodhound POST request

Tags: jquery, typeahead, typeahead.js, twitter-typeahead

I cannot seem to get a remote query to use POST properly.

```
var creditors = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: function (d) {
        return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.value)
    },
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: {
        url: "../getCreditors",
        replace: function(url, query) {
            return url + "#" + query;
        },
        ajax : {
            type: "POST",
            data: $.param({q: queryInput.val()})
        }
    }
});
```

the queryInput.val() does not get the current value of the object only the value at the time bloodhound object is instantiated. How can I get the query string into the ajax data options?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46927923/3966458 without ajax

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use beforeSend of $.ajax

```
var creditors = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: function (d) {
        return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.value)
    },
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: {
        url: "../getCreditors",

        replace: function(url, query) {
            return url + "#" + query;
        },
        ajax : {
            beforeSend: function(jqXhr, settings){
               settings.data = $.param({q: queryInput.val()})
            },
            type: "POST"

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Although this code does call the Ajax method when it should, it doesn't set Content-Type correctly, so ASP.NET MVC, at least, doesn't parse the posted data.

Comment: This will send with a content-type of "text/plain; charset=UTF-8", if you want it to send as json (like me :D) you'll need to set the content type on the jqXhr object like so:

jqXhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');

Comment: Since you're already calling replace, you can use that to store the query to a local variable that you use in beforeSend. It removes the coupling to queryInput.

Comment: @Snekse Can you explain your comment a bit more? I tried adding a line in replace `this.q = query` and replacing `queryInput.val()` with `this.q` but `this.q` shows as `undefined` in debugger `beforeSend` function.

Comment: This [doesn't work anymore](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/1236). The code in @Atropo's answer does work.

Answer (score 13):

You can use the `prepare` property with `remote` or `prefetch`, mind that the function signature changes.
An example with `prefetch`:

```
var Bloodhound = new Bloodhound({
                datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
                queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
                prefetch: {
                    url: remote,
                    prepare: function (settings) {
                        settings.type = "POST";
                        settings.contentType = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
                        return settings;
                    },
                    remote: function (query, settings) {
                        settings.type = "POST";
                        settings.data = {q: query, foo: 'bar'}; // you can pass some data if you need to
                        return settings;
                    }
                }
            });
```

Remember that with `remote` the function signature changes with `function(query, settings)`.

For reference: [github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/1236](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/1236)

Comment: You can pass your custom `data` if you need to (e.g. the current value of another field etc.). The current typed-in value will be in the `query` variable

Answer (score 0):

I found the ajax 'beforeSend' method holylaw mentioned worked the best.

It was important to alter the url as well though. Otherwise Typeahead didn't bother making another request. So I just added a bogus parameter at the end of the url. Like this

> http://mylittleservice.com?blah=%QUERY

That way when the ajax data packaged changed I was assured a fresh request to the server.